# MySQL Create Table Like with Engine override

Tags: mysql, wordpress, innodb, myisam, multiple-databases

I am in the process of breaking up a wordpress site with one database and 81,000+ tables into a multi-DB using a plugin by wpmudev.org. The main motivator is performance and I checked the tables itself and they are of type MyISAM.

I was thinking that while moving the tables into new databases I could also change the table type to InnoDB which should see a site performance improvement.

The script to migrate tables from the existing db to the new db uses the following syntax:

CREATE TABLE .... LIKE ....
INSERT INTO .... SELECT * FROM ....

I could not locate information if I could oveerride the engine in the CREATE TABLE command such as:

CREATE TABLE .... LIKE .... ENGINE=InnoDB

Also I am wondering if "INSERT INTO .... SELECT * FROM ...." is the most efficient way to insert the data... This is a php script so I don't mind adding a little code to improve the performance which - at an earlier trial took 3 days to run on a 4-core 4GB RAM!

Comment: 81,000 tables - are you sure you dont mean tuples ?

Comment: No, tables. It's a Wordpress MU site. More than 8000 blogs, each of which requires at least 3 tables.... I can't even connect with a normal Admin tool as they all try to get the schema and time out ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can't specify ENGINE parametr with `create table like...` syntax, but here are some alternatives:

```
CREATE TABLE `another_table` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `original`
```

... will copy table structure and data, without keys and trigers

```
CREATE TABLE `another_table` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `original` WHERE 0
```

... will copy just structure, but no data (because `WHERE 0` will filter all out)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `another_table` ) ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `original`
```

... maybe, you would like to add `TEMPORARY` word, then DB would automatically remove the table when you close the connection

```
CREATE TABLE `another_table` ( INDEX(`id_column`) ) ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `original`
```

... and this is an example on how to recreate the keys in new table (syntax of defining keys as the same as in simple CREATE TABLE syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've done just this (override the table type).  Works fine.

For big transfers like this I've generally done some form of database dump,
a script to massage the data (e.g. change engine types), then a restore to the new database.  The text based database dumps mostly use `COPY` which is faster than `INSERT INTO`.

You can also issue `ALTER TABLE {} ENGINE=INNODB;`.  Though that said a fresh start has a lot going for it also.

81,000 tables. Wow.

Answer (score 2):

This question was also answered indirectly by another question, which helped me as I was trying to clone a table into the MEMORY engine:
[how-to-copy-mysql-table-structure-to-table-in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097088/how-to-copy-mysql-table-structure-to-table-in-memory)

```
CREATE TABLE % ENGINE=InnoDB SELECT * FROM %
```

Hope this helps someone as it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
 CREATE TABLE `another_table` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM `original` LIMIT 0
```